# Database refactoring to many-to-many relation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

During some database refactoring where i need to introduce a future many-to-many relation, i've stumbled across somthing i think must be possible.

Given an original table:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  field1 varchar, 
  field2 varchar, 
  field3 varchar 
);
```

and a newly created table:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  field1 varchar, 
  field2 varchar 
);
```

i'd like to move the contents of field1 and field2 from a to b. In order to accomodate a many-to-many relation, an association table is also available:

```
CREATE TABLE a_b (
  aid serial NOT NULL,
  bid serial NOT NULL
);
```

Here the original a-id's and the newly created b-id's should end.

Thus, if i start off with an a-table like this

```
| 33 | John | Jane | Juli |
| 34 | Fred | Carl | Josh |
```

i'd like to see it end up in the b-table:

```
| 1 | John | Jane
| 2 | Fred | Carl
```

and the association a_b

```
| 33 | 1 |
| 34 | 2 |
```

The original table will then remove field1 and field2 removed and therefore i'll look like this

```
| 1 | Juli |
| 2 | Josh |
```

I immediately thought of using with-queries, but have found no way to get it to work. 
This obviously does not work:

```
WITH new AS (
    INSERT INTO b (field1, field2) 
    SELECT field1, field2 FROM a
    RETURNING id
  )
INSERT INTO a_b (???, bid) SELECT * FROM new;
```

but illustrates the problem. I've found no way of inserting into b while maintaining a relationship with the corresponding a-id's. I think it must be possible.

Any thoughts?

Søren

PS I've omitteded things like foreign keys for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Brevity is not your friend. When something is missing, we can't tell whether you're being brief or whether you've made a big mistake.

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id serial primary key,
  field1 varchar, 
  field2 varchar, 
  field3 varchar 
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id serial primary key,
  field1 varchar, 
  field2 varchar 
);
```

"Association" tables store foreign keys; yours should store the id number from "a" and the id number from "b". So it should be declared like this.

```
CREATE TABLE a_b (
  aid integer NOT NULL,
  bid integer NOT NULL,
  primary key (aid, bid),
  foreign key (aid) references a (id),
  foreign key (bid) references b (id)
);
```

Let's add a few rows to "a". Look closely at the duplication in the second and third rows below, "Fred" and "Carl".

```
insert into a (field1, field2, field3) values
('John', 'Jane', 'Juli'),
('Fred', 'Carl', 'Josh'),
('Fred', 'Carl', 'Abby'),
('Art', 'Carl', 'Abby');
```

To populate "b", insert distinct (unique) combinations from a.

```
insert into b (field1, field2)
select distinct field1, field2 
from a;

select * from b;
```

```
id  field1  field2
--
1   John    Jane
2   Art     Carl
3   Fred    Carl
```

The "association" table needs id numbers from "a", along with their corresponding id numbers from "b". You need to join "a" and "b".

```
insert into a_b
select a.id aid, b.id bid
from a
inner join b on a.field1 = b.field1 and a.field2 = b.field2
```

Now you can join those three tables to see the full associations. It's often useful to create a view based on a query like this one.

```
select b.id bid, b.field1, b.field2, a.id aid, a.field3
from a_b
inner join a on a.id = a_b.aid
inner join b on b.id = a_b.bid
order by a.id;
```

```
bid  field1  field2 aid  field3
--
1    John    Jane   1    Juli
3    Fred    Carl   2    Josh
3    Fred    Carl   3    Abby
2    Art     Carl   4    Abby
```

When you're satisfied that the data is right, you can drop the columns "field1" and "field2" from a.